# Add div background image in email template

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates

I have created a custom email template and I want to add background image to one of its div element. I have added `html` file in my email with below content.

```
<div
  class="container"
  width="100%"
  style="
    background-image: url('{{view url=\"My_Module/img/myimage.png\"}}');
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-size: cover;
  "
>
```

But its not working. It removes whole style tag from my div in final email.
If I am using complete image static url, it works correctly like below.

```
<div
  class="container"
  width="100%"
  style="
    background-image: url('http://domain.com/my-full-image-path/myimage.png');
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-size: cover;
  "
>
```

Please note here that I want to add background image and not `img` field with `src`. I have checked and found that the image path is correct so no issues with image path here.
Does anyone know how we can add background image in email template content.